# How to convert a string into the literal meaning?

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I want to write a general function that can take in different machine learning algorithms and it's parameters and initialise a model.

I wrote:

```
def create_model(model_name,kernel='rbf',C=1.0):
      clf = model_name()
print(create_model('SVC'))
```

and the error is:

> clf = model_name()
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I understand the error is saying you can't have a string ('SVC') as a model object. So then I tried adding `evaluate(model_name)()` to turn the string into an object but got `name 'evaluate' is not defined`.

Could someone show me the correct way to do this? I want to do this so then I can add a set of optional parameters to the function, and then e.g. replace SVC with logistic regression in the same function.

Comment: Don't turn it into a string in the first place.  Try `create_model(SVC)`.  I.e. pass the actual model class object, not the _name_ of the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not murderously sure that you can trust the strings passed for `model_name`, create a dict mapping acceptable string values to their classes.

```
models = [modelA, modelB, modelC]
name2model = {model.__name__: model for model in models}

def create_model(model_name, *args, **kwargs):
      return name2model[model_name](*args, **kwargs)
```

edit: this of course assumes that you have to deal with string names in the first place, e.g. from user input. Otherwise, see Samwises' comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, this could be the automation you're looking for:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

model_dict = {
'logr': LogisticRegression(),
'rf': RandomForestClassifier(),
'svc': SVC()
}

def create_model(model_name, kernel='rbf', C=1.0):
    clf = model_dict[model_name]
    return clf

for mod in model_dict.keys():
    model = create_model(mod)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    print(mod, accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

However, there are different hyperparameters params for different models, so the function `create_model()` will not be able to make use of `C=1.0` for the various models.

This automation could be useful for baseline model performance, then you will only need these codes:

```
model_dict = {
'logr': LogisticRegression(),
'rf': RandomForestClassifier(),
'svc': SVC()
}

for mod in model_dict.keys():
    model = model_dict[mod]
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    print(mod, accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```